# Define a new location block in NGINX Locations

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I defined a new server block in my NGINX config file.

```
server {

    server_name hotelshokouh.ir;

    error_log /var/www/filis.com/_error.log;
    index index.php;

    root /var/www/filis.com/;
    location / {
    }

    location /site/ {
        root /var/www/filis.com/admin/site/;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/options;
}
```

I want if user come to  `(/site/)`, server show `"/admin/site/"` folder as root

but my code don't work!
Do you know what is my wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The path to the file is formed by concatenating the value of `root` with the requested URI. So your configuration is looking for the URI `/site/foo` at the location `/var/www/filis.com/admin/site/site/foo`.

Try:

```
location /site/ {
    root /var/www/filis.com/admin;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.